# Mongodb "errmsg":"Client sent an HTTP request over a native MongoDB connection"

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

Instance hosted in oracle private subnet configured via loadbalancer , when access from out side it from loadbalncer public IP  gives this error.

```
"errmsg":"Client sent an HTTP request over a native MongoDB connection"
```

Technology springboot , oracle cloud, mongodb 7

Telnet via 27017 working

Comment: MongoDB has no http interface. What do you try to do?

Comment: I have a vm instance in oracle cloud  which running a mongodb. However, my subnet is a private subnet. So my requirement is I need to access this mongodb instance via internet (outside from the cloud). Only solution is oci loadbalncer. which is already configured.

Comment: This the details error in spring boot com.mongodb.MongoInternalException: The reply message length 1347703880 is greater than the maximum message length 33554432
 at com.mongodb.internal.connection.MessageHeader.<init>(MessageHeader.java:41) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.1.1.jar:?]
 at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveResponseBuffers(InternalStreamConnection.java:651) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.1.1.jar:?]
 at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveMessageWithAdditionalTimeout(InternalStreamConnection.java:513) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.1.1.jar

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `telnet` or `curl` or tools of that kind to connect to *and actually interact with* MongoDB.  The default port 27017 on which `mongod` is listening requires a connection from one of the 20 or so supported client-side drivers (java, javascript, C, python, etc. etc.)   `telnet` connect works but the moment you try to pass traffic through the connection you will get the native connection error.